# Looping back to a command and changing a variable?

Tags: batch-file

Okay, I am new to the programming world and I may be asking for too much but, I was trying to see if this is possible. I am trying to grab all the serial numbers in a range of IP Addresses but, im only able to do it one octet at a time for example:

```
(FOR /L %%s IN (1,1,254) DO wmic /node:193.257.1.%%s %ustring% %pstring% bios get serialnumber) >> "C:\Users\abraham.alaniz\Desktop\SerialNumber1.log"`
```

I'd like to be able to loop back to the same command and change the 1 in "/node:193.257.1.%%s" to, "2", and continue to do so. I can always just copy and paste the whole command over again and change it that way but, it just looks messy! Any ideas?

Comment: Use a nested loop (a loop within a loop). The first FOR can use %%s as a variable, the second %%t.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou dont wan't to feel dumb or anything but, do you mind actually showing me how?

Comment: `(FOR /L %%T IN (1,1,2) do (` your loop `/node:193.257.%%T.%%s` here `) ) >> SerialNumber1.log` - in short.

Comment: @echo off

set ustring=
set pstring=
set ustring=/user:"%user%"
set pstring=/password:"%pass%"
'(FOR /L %%T IN (1,1,254) DO wmic /node:10.227.%%T.%%s %ustring% %pstring% bios get serialnumber) >> "C:\Users\abraham.alaniz\Desktop\SerialNumber1.log"'                                                                                 Where does the %%s get its command from?

Comment: From your inner loop. `FOR /L %%T IN (1,1,254) DO FOR /L %%S IN (1,1,254) DO ...`

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I figured it out right after, thank you!